# Eclipse Photon - plugin installed but not available

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have just installed Eclipse photon (4.8.0)

I install, through 'market place', my favorite plugins: 
 yaml editor, yedit, yatta, themes, shell, etc..

The plugins installed well, and then prompt for restart.

But after the restart, nothing is here, nothing is available (no yatta button in the bar, no yml editor, no new theme, no shell view etc..).

It's like there is nothing.

If I go in 'installation details' I see the plugins as 'installed'.

I am confused here...

Example of plugins:

```
  TM Terminal   4.1.0.201603090932  org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - Target Management
  Wicked Shell  2.0.6   net.sf.wickedshell.feature.feature.group    Stefan Reichert
  Yaml Editor   0.4.0   de.jcup.yamleditor.feature.group    Albert Tregnaghi
  YEdit Feature 1.0.20.201509041456-RELEASE org.dadacoalition.yedit.feature.feature.group   YEdit Project
```

Comment: Check for an Activities or Capabilities preference page and see if you need to enable anything there.

Comment: I dont find this options in windows > preferences ..

Comment: Not related, but you should consider using https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-wild-web-developer-web-development-eclipse-ide as an alternative to Yaml Editor and YEdit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse was installed as 'Administrator' and then run 'normally' (as a user).

Reinstalling all as user solved the problem.